# Xml Parse Edit Save and Create In Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, dom4j

I have to Parse XML as of now i have used SAX parser now i have to display, edit it and in end create XML the issue is now how do i do that with SAX Parser because it does not have that feature. I am in tough situation, also i have searched things about dom4j and DOM. My code is shown below.

```
public class XmlBack extends DefaultHandler {

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {        
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("VarGroup")) {
            varGroupVariables = new HashMap<String, List<VarGroupVariable>>();
        }else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Variable")) {
            varGroupVariable = new VarGroupVariable();
            nameAttribute = attributes.getValue("Name");
            varGroupVariable.setName(nameAttribute);
        }else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("TYP")) {
            btype = true;
        }else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("VALUE")) {
            bvalue = true;
        }       
    }
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        String vtype = null;

        if (btype) {
            vtype = new String(ch, start, length);
            varGroupVariable.setType(vtype);
            btype = false;
        }

        Double value = null;
        if (bvalue) {
            String vvalue = new String(ch, start, length);
            try {
                value = Double.valueOf(vvalue);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
                value = 0d;
            }
            varGroupVariable.setValue(value);
            bvalue = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Variable")) {
            String varGroupVariableName = varGroupVariable.getName().split("\\.")[0];
            String name = varGroupVariableName.substring(0,varGroupVariableName.length() - 1);
            String name1= varGroupVariableName = varGroupVariable.getName().split("\\.")[1];
            System.out.println(name1);
            List<VarGroupVariable> varGroupVariablesList;
            if(varGroupVariables.containsKey(name)) {
                varGroupVariablesList = varGroupVariables.get(name);                 
            }else {
                varGroupVariablesList = new ArrayList<VarGroupVariable>();
            }
            int serial = varGroupVariablesList.size();
            varGroupVariable.setSerial(++serial);
            varGroupVariablesList.add(varGroupVariable);        
            varGroupVariables.put(name, varGroupVariablesList);
            //System.out.println(name+"\n");
            }
    }
    private int no = 1;
    boolean bcore,bmold,bvalue,btype = false;
    String nameAttribute;
    Map<String, List<VarGroupVariable>> varGroupVariables;
    VarGroupVariable varGroupVariable;
}
```

Comment: What's the exact problem? You have (successfully, I hope) parse XML into memory. Edit/change the values and structures as you like, and then write it out. I suspect you will find using a DOM easier as most have tools to change values, structures and write it out. FWIW I use nu.xom XOM

Comment: Thanks For Reply. My Issue is till display i have used sax parser and now it does not create XML is it possible to use DOM now or do i have to change the code/parser SAX to DOM.

Comment: What method do i need to use to parse edit and create xml file. JDom,Dom,Sax,Dom4j. Please Provide a clear idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your XML isn't unreasonably complex, or if you have a schema for it available) the easiest option is probably JAXB. There are several tutorials around, for example  [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/). Of course, StackOverflow is also a good source for JAXB knowledge.